# What is the number of permutations of N values or less in N space

Tags: permutations

Given a number N what is the number of Permutations in a Space of size N, of these N values.

Example:
N=2

$${P} = \{ (0,0,0), (0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(1,1,0),(0,1,2),(1,0,2),(0,2,1),(1,2,0),(2,0,1),(2,1,0)\}$$

The restrictions to this are:

1. All Values have to be in the range of  $\{0 ,..., (N-1)\}$
2. in a permutation with only $k$ unique values, these unique values have to be in the range $\{0 ,..., (k-1)\}$

basically, we exclude permutations like $(1,1,1)$, because they are the same as $(0,0,0)$, all equal values.
we exclude $(0,0,2)$, because there exists an equivalent permutation $(0,0,1)$, with a lower maximum value.

One more way to describe this, is if you are given a set of N values, possibly distinct or not, and you only know the inequallities or equalities between the values in the set. Choose the lowest number $k$, so that the set contains only the values ranging from $0$ to $k$ and still fullfills all the inequalities and equalites.
example:
$$(a,b,c), a<b, a<c, b>c$$
would give you the set $(0,2,1)$.

The question is, how many sets/permutations are there, if you are given a space of size N (in terms of N).

For $N = 2$, it should be $3 = 2^2-1$

For $N = 3$, it should be $13 = 2^3-1+3!$

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) except you care to remember the label on each part in the partition rather than treating them as unlabeled (*evidenced by (1,0,1) being treated as different than (0,1,0)*).  The same logic to generating those values should apply here, just rather just $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{n\brace k}$ you also have a factorial so it is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk!{n\brace k}$

Comment: The sequence continues $3,13,75,541,4683,\dots$  See http://oeis.org/A000670 and [Ordered Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) for more.